# Index optimised for specific lookup

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization, indexing

I have a table (which could potentially grow large, ~ millions of rows) on which I regularly perform the query `SELECT * from table WHERE somefield = 20`, and I would like this query to run fast. At any time, I expect this query to return at most 10 rows out of possiby millions, for this specific value 20 (no guarantees for any other values). What would be the proper way to index this? Is it sufficient to just place an index on somefield, and make sure statistics are roughly up to date? Or are then any other tricks I could try to optimise this?

Comment: I've voted to move this to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal index for this query **in isolation** would be an index with key column `somefield` and included columns of all other columns in the table (either by making the index clustered or an NCI with the `INCLUDE` option).

This would allow the values to be seeked into directly and avoid the need for bookmark lookups.

But the maintenance overhead of an NCI with all those included columns would affect data modification operations and you might prefer a CI defined on different key columns to benefit other queries or to avoid fragmentation anyway

So for that reason you may well prefer to define an NCI on `somefield` alone and live with the 10 bookmark lookups. It is a balancing act.

**Edit.** Actually if you are **only** interested in optimising the query where `somefield = 20` then you could just create a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) on that value. I likely would then `include` all columns in that index definition.

Comment: Filtered index, that seems exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

> Is it sufficient to just place an index on somefield, and make sure statistics are roughly up to date?

Yes, quite simply. Make sure somefield is the right type (ie. int). If somefield needs to contain text there's more you can do, but otherwise a normal index will be fine.

You can get small increases (and I do mean *small*) if you don't need every field returned by not using `SELECT *` (you won't need somefield, presumably, as you already know what it is).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You would want to add an index on somefield.

If you are not doing other queries, then you may want to make it a clustered index, but without context, it's hard to say conclusively.